# Any effects on performance in C program with multiple dependancy

Tags: c, include

I have received a code base which has stated multiple dependencies (multiple `#include`s) but the program itself does not use them.

Will there be any performance issues if I include multiple files in a C program without using them?

Comment: It slows the compilation slightly. It won’t affect the performance of the executable.  Changes in the irrelevant dependencies will mean unnecessary recompilation.

Comment: That also increase binary size

Comment: @KillianGardahaut No, unused includes do not affect the binary size.